# Limit keywords for day in a Google Analytics API request

Tags: limit, keyword, google-analytics-api

I'd like to know if there's a way to get the top 5 keywords by grouping them by days of the current month.

I'd like to receive a dataset like the following as result.
Supposing today is 4 of December i want to retrieve data for days from 1 to 4 of December, limiting the number of keywords for day to 5:

```
Day Keyword     Visits
----------------------
01  keyword1    703
01  keyword2    688
01  keyword3    115
02  keyword1    109
02  keyword2    66
02  keyword3    53
02  keyword4    40
02  keyword5    23
03  keyword1    23
03  keyword2    19
03  keyword3    17
04  keyword1    14
04  keyword2    14
```

What i've currently done is setting the following parameters:
(you can test it here if you have a ganalytics account: http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html)

```
Dimensions: ga:day,ga:keyword
Metrics: ga:visits
Filters: ga:medium==organic;ga:keyword!=(not provided)
Sort: ga:day,-ga:visits,ga:keyword
```

Now i just need a method to limit the number of keywords for day (if possible).